# ELSA 3.0 - Invoking manually registered workflows using the IWorkflowRuntime service

Tags: elsa-workflows

I've created and registered a workflow as described [here](https://v3.elsaworkflows.io/docs/guides/invoking-workflows#using-the-i-workflow-runtime-service).

```
class DailyReport : WorkflowBase { ... }

services.AddElsa(elsa => elsa.AddWorkflow<DailyReport>());
```

If I start it using IWorkflowRuntime, I get the "Specified workflow definition and version does not exist" exception.

```
var runtime = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkflowRuntime>();

var result = await runtime.StartWorkflowAsync("DailyReport");
```

If I run the workflow using IWorkflowRunner, it runs just fine.

```
var runner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkflowRunner>();

var result = await runner.RunAsync(new DailyReport());
```

What am I missing here?